# I need a mathematical function where y decreases faster as x increases

Tags: math

Here is a graph to display the type of function i'd like, I'm not incredible at mathematics so this is quite a difficult wall for me.

[image]

https://gyazo.com/1c8011af71cad9a5698f47e75f736ad7

It looks like a steady decrease but I was thinking more of a negative exponent?

Comment: What's the context? Are you simply asking for the _mathematical term_ to describe a function like this, or are you after a function-definition that matches that curve? If you're after a definition do you want a symbolic/algebraic definition or a numeric definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, it does look like a negative exponential plot.

As a quick approximation I came up with:

```
f( x ) = -e ^ ( x / 20 ) + 16
```

It's not perfect though:

[image]